# Group mapping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, underscore.js

Can I make some kind of a mapping in JavaScript?

Right now I can do

```
if (number < 32) {
  group = 1;
else if (number < 72) {
  group = 2;
} else if (number < 100) {
  group = 3;
} else {
  group = -1;
}
```

Instead of doing this, I want an inline mapping. I could put it in a function, but I wonder if javascript has any smart way to do this, having the group divisions defined in an array or something.

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do, but maybe you are looking for a switch statement https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: I don't think you can find built-in functionality for this, but if you write a function, you can invoke it "inline".

Answer (score 2):

You can use a switch to make it little more readable, but if you want it inline:

```
var group = number < 32 ? 1 : number < 72 ? 2 : number < 100 ? 3 : -1;
```

Comment: Don't you need braces in there?

Comment: I think no, it doesn't need it. Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/b2L4d2n7/)

Comment: In fact you could use braces if you want, but it isn't necessary 

Answer (score 1):

If your grouping check is always the same (number < bound) you could use a JavaScript object to store your bounds and the related group.

```
//groups object structure
var groups = {
    32: 1,
    72: 2,
    100: 3,
};

function getGroup(number, groups) {
    for (var bound in groups) {
        if (number < bound) {
            return groups[bound];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

//can be invoked like this
var group = getGroup(40, {32:1, 72:2, 100:3});
```

You can iterate on all the object's properties using JS's for-in, note that bound in this case is the label (i.e. 32, 72, etc.)

The groups object can also be stored as text in a json file and loaded at runtime if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different data structures you can use:

### Array

```
var groups = [32, 72, 100];
var number = 99; // change number here
var group = -1; // default group
$.each(groups, function (i, n) {
    if (number < n) {
        group = i + 1; // add 1 because array index starts at 0
        return false; // break the loop
    }
});
console.log(group); // 3
```

---

### Object

```
var groups = {1:32, 2:72, 3:100};
var number = 100; // change number here
var group = -1; // default group
$.each(groups, function (i, n) {
    if (number < n) {
        group = i;
        return false; // break the loop
    }
});
console.log(group); // -1
```